# SSH public key not Working - No supported authentication methods available

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, public-key, public-key-encryption

I'm trying to allow another developer to connect to a our ubuntu server and they are getting the below error in FileZilla.

> ```
> Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
> Could not connect to server
> ```

[image]

I thought, maybe I added the public key to the `~/.ssh/authorised_keys` on the server incorrectly.

She sent me a public key like this called `mags_public_key`

```
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: "mags-key-20140819"
AAAAB3N????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
????x?????????????????????????????BKCx1M1S/Mhh3MHw==
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
```

Which is odd as I'm not used to comments in public keys or line breaks?  We've tried using her public key with & witout the comment & line breaks.  I've added it to `~/.ssh/authorised_keys` like this:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB/??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????3cXMJMA8zT
AAAAB3N??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????BKCx1M1S/Mhh3MHw==
```

It's also strange as it does not begin with `ssh-rsa`, also her private key is called *mags_private.ppk*, I think this is because she is using windows & putty.  I'm used to adding keys which are called `id_rsa.pub`

Is their a problem with her public key or do I need to add something to the authorised_keys file.  Other devs have been able to ssh in before but they had a `id_rsa.pub`.

Comment: Let the other developer to export the public key in the openssh format from puttygen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The safest way to convert to openssh format without introducing a typo is to have her open her private key in PuTTY's  "puttygen" graphical utility.  At the top of the dialog box should be a textbox labelled "Public key for pasting into OpenSSH authorized_keys file" which does just what it says.

Alternately, on your system, use ssh-keygen's *import* option

```
$ ssh-keygen -i -f file_to_convert > output
```

Comment: thanks, so does it look like her public key is in the incorrect format? How can you tell?  She has told me she has used it many times to connect to a server.

Comment: I used that command you gave me to convert it.  It seemed to only remove the line breaks, comment and it prepended `ssh-rsa `. Hopefully it works, thanks