# I can't connect to my VM on Google cloud

Tags: ssh, virtual-machines, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I can't SSH my VM server, every time I tried it failed, please help:

1. I can't connect to it via the browser, the error code is : (#79)
2. I also can't SSH to my server via SSH client [See Connection error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNFS8.png)

btw, I already uploaded the SSH public key to the METADATA and also the private key to PUTTY:

```
rsa-key-20181119    ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAv6/V…dqLXj6O9PiFWeUnPQimuQ== rsa-key-20181119
```

Answer (score 1):

Google provides an [ssh troubleshooting guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh). I suggest going through it. If the guide does not resolve the problem, the troubleshooting guide mentions connecting via serial console. connect via the serial console, & ensure the [Linux guest environment](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/linux-guest-environment#wgei_packages) is running.

I will also suggest you check [this guide](https://gist.github.com/feczo/7282a6e00181fde4281b) to ensure you're using putty & the metadata SSH keys correctly.

If none of the above works, [there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204400/ssh-public-key-no-supported-authentication-methods-available-server-sent-publ), [are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294381/google-server-putty-connect-disconnected-no-supported-authentication-methods-a), [many](https://serverfault.com/questions/793201/ssh-public-key-not-working-no-supported-authentication-methods-available), other questions & answers about the "no supported authentication methods supported" error message.